# How do I change Add button & Search labels in list view in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony2-easyadmin

[image]

How do I change Search & Add labels in List view ?

Answer (score 9):

To change lable for search and new action button on list add this in yml.

```
list:
    actions:        
        - { name: 'search', label: 'My Search'}
        - { name: 'new', label: 'My New action'}
```